# Get band number of maximum value per pixel for multiband raster in R

Tags: raster, r

I have a multiband raster and I want to find the band number of the maximum value for each pixel.

Here is some example code:

```
library(raster)
set.seed(42)
r1 <- raster(nrow=4, ncol=4)
r1[] <- round(runif(ncell(r1)) * 10)
r2 = raster(nrow=4,ncol=4)
r2[] = round(runif(ncell(r2)) * 10)
values(r1)
values(r2)

rast = brick(r1,r2)
```

Obviously, I can find the maximum value for each pixel, but I want to know from which band it came. In the above example `values(r1) = [1] 9 9 3 8 6 5 7 1 7 7 5 7 9 3 5 9` and `values(r2) = [1] 10  1  5  6  9  1 10  9  1  5  4  9  4  8  7  8`

```
max(rast) = [1] 10  9  5  8  9  5 10  9  7  7  5  9  9  8  7  9
```

So I want a raster that eventually looks like [2 1 1 1(2?) . . . . 1].

How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution directly from the raster package. I have noticed that it operates strangely in cases where there is a tie value - reporting both bands as one integer (i.e. a tie between bands 1 and 2 leaves you with a 12. Using `whiches.max()` you can get a raster that indicates the band number with the maximum per-pixel value in your raster brick.

To take it a step further, I use a `for` loop to iterate through each unique max-value-containing band (so it's scalable beyond 2-layer raster bricks, even if one layer never has a max), then create a new raster and replace its contents with the pixel-wise max from the appropriate brick layer.

```
# Identify pixel-wise band with max value - this is what you were asking about
pixelMaxBand.ras = whiches.max(rast)
plot(pixelMaxBand.ras)

# A step further
# Identify bands that contain a max value
maxBands = unique(pixelMaxBand.ras)    
# Create a raster that matches dimensions
outRas = rast[[1]]
# Populate raster using appropriate layers from original brick
for(i in 1:length(maxBands)){
  myBand = maxBands[i]
  outRas[pixelMaxBand.ras == myBand] <- rast[[myBand]][pixelMaxBand.ras == myBand]
}

plot(rast[[1]])
plot(rast[[2]])
plot(outRas)
```

Comment: That's perfect. I hadn't ever seen the whiches.max() function. Cheers.